# Need command to show fingers (two circle) in IOS simulator

Tags: iphone, ios

I am a blackberry developer. I'm new to IOS. I need to check for pinch events on IOS simulator. I googled it and saw images of two circles. Can you please tell me how I will get swipe (pinch or 2 circle) so that I can check my code?
Please give me any command, for example cmd+shift+2.

I am checking on iPad 6.0 simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **option key** on your keyboard. This will create two circles on the screen to indicate and mimic a two finger tap and pinch.

Answer (score 0):

I think you hold the command key when you click on the simulator. Might be Option though.